# are there advantages for using value class (without methods) vs type alias?

Tags: scala

Let's say I have this ADT :

```
case class Person(id: String)
case class Kid(id: String, name: String)
```

I would like to represent the ***id*** field in more explicit and type safe way. I have two options

## 1. type alias

```
type PersonId = String
case class Person(id: PersonId)
case class Kid(id: String, name: PersonId)
```

## 2. value class

```
case class PersonId(id: String) extends AnyVal
case class Person(id: PersonId)
case class Kid(id: String, name: PersonId)
```

Which approach is more idiomatic?
Are there any advantages of using value class in this case (no additional methods)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Type aliases are purely a syntactic convenience—in some cases they can make code cleaner or easier to refactor, but they don't provide any additional type safety. For example, suppose I've got some code like this:

```
type DegreesC = Double
type DegreesF = Double

def c2f(c: DegreesC): DegreesF = (c * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32
```

And a value representing the current temperature in Fahrenheit:

```
val currentTempInF = 62.0
```

The compiler is happy to let me pass this to my `c2f` method:

```
scala> c2f(currentTempInF)
res1: DegreesF = 143.6
```

Value classes give you more type safety without the runtime cost of an additional allocation for the case class (although there is still a syntactic cost):

```
case class DegreesC(value: Double) extends AnyVal
case class DegreesF(value: Double) extends AnyVal

def c2f(c: DegreesC): DegreesF = DegreesF((c.value * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32)

val currentTempInF = DegreesF(62.0)
```

And then:

```
scala> c2f(currentTempInF)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : DegreesF
 required: DegreesC
       c2f(currentTempInF)
           ^
```

Which you prefer is a matter of taste. Personally I think type aliases in Scala are often overused and oversold, but I also tend to avoid value classes because they have weird limitations and bugs, and the runtime performance benefits they offer often aren't that important to me. In any case I wouldn't say one approach or the other is more idiomatic (if anything I'd give that status to a plain, non-value class case class).

Answer (score 2):

For your specific use case (no additional methods). The big advantage is type safety. If you declare PersonId to be a type like this

```
type PersonId = String
```

your Kid case class will take any string as an argument for it's constructor.
but if you will declare PersonId with value type

```
 case class PersonId(id: String) extends AnyVal
```

your Kid class will only accept a PersonId as an argument, this way you communicate the fact that this is not just any string but an actual PersonId.

The advantage of extending AnyVal over a regular case class is that it comes with no runtime overhead in most of the time.
You can checkout this [link](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Type aliases just provide an alias but no type safety.

```
type PersonId = String
case class Person(id: PersonId)

Person("some random string")
```

Compiles and runs without error

```
case class PersonId(id: String) extends AnyVal
case class Person(id: PersonId)

Person("some random string")
```

Fails at compile time with a type error